# Connect to FTP over TLS/SSL (FTPS) server from Java stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, ftps

Hi, 
I've made code to upload file to FTP and FTPS (over TLS/SSL) servers both. It works well on local eclipse test but only FTPS uploading failed when it is running on Oracle java stored procedure. From the connection point it's got errror.

sys info:

- Eclipse java version - "1.8.0_151"
- Oracle java version - "1.8.0_91"
- commons-net-3.6
- Oracle DB - 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient;

public class Test 
{     
    public static void setGroFilesToFtp()
    {    
        FTPSClient ftps = null;

        try {
            ftps = new FTPSClient();            
            ftps.connect("host", 21);

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
}
```

```
java.net.SocketException: connect failed, 10022

Àß¸øµÈ ÀÎ¼ö¸¦ ÀÔ·ÂÇß½À´Ï´Ù.

at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient._connect(SocketClient.java)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java)
at FtpTransfer.setGroFilesToFtp(FtpTransfer:22)
```

Comment: Oracle does not allow outbound network calls without setting up some Access Control Lists.  See here - http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_11g_new_acls_plsql.htm

Comment: It seems not working.

Comment: It seems not working. I've applied the next code.

BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.create_acl (
    acl          => 'acl_test.xml', 
    description  => 'test description',
    principal    => 'USER_ID',
    is_grant     => TRUE, 
    privilege    => 'connect',
    start_date   => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    end_date     => NULL);

  COMMIT;
END;
/

BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.assign_acl (
    acl => 'acl_test.xml',
    host => 'HOST', 
    lower_port =>21,
    upper_port => NULL); 
    
  COMMIT;    
END;

Comment: One thing the suspectable is simple FTP server connection is working but FTPS server connection is not working. Any body give me help please...

Comment: SFTP is usually port 22

Comment: Port 22 occurs exception "org.apache.commons.net.MalformedServerReplyException" on eclipse and to say nothing on Oracle. And it's not SFTP, it's STP over TLS/SSL.

Comment: The strange thing is my local system can not ping the FTPS server. But no idea how eclipse to connect to the server and upload file.

Comment: Please any body give me help!!! i'm eager to get it.